# Apache/PHP gets stuck although there are enough resources

Tags: apache-httpd, php

The server has a 4C/8T CPU and 32GB RAM. OS: Debian 12. Apache/PHP becomes unresponsive after ~500MB usage. I tried PHP8.2 and PHP8.1, but the result is the same. If I restart PHP, Apache starts responding. I checked the Apache error log, and there is only a warning as below, there are no other types of error on the error log.

[Tue Nov 28 13:50:31.932468 2023] [http2:warn] [pid 13336:tid 139689031698112] [client 10.41.23.50:34858] h2_stream(13336-348-1,CLEANUP): started=1, scheduled=1, ready=0, out_buffer=0

[image: PHP usage]

[image: Top]

Comment: Have you checked the limits on Apache and PHP processes? Number of concurrent connections?

Comment: It was a network issue, the network gets 100% for a period of time, and then the server becomes unresponsive to Apache requests although there is no load on Apache. I limited the process which was using the network to lower than 80% of network bandwidth, and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out the problem was with child process limit for PHP. There were no related error on logs but the problem is solved when I increased the limit from 10 to 100.

One process was using around 50MB so after 10 process, the limit was reached. Although there are more server resources, it could not be used and Php service becomes unresponsive.